# Error generating SQLite db in visual studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, sqlite

I am transitioning from using SQL Server to SQLite for the first time. I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I have downloaded and installed

```
 sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.103.0.exe
```

from https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
and have installed the following NuGet packages

```
EntityFramework version=6.0.0 
System.Data.SQLite version=1.0.103 
System.Data.SQLite.Core version=1.0.103 
System.Data.SQLite.EF6 version=1.0.103 
System.Data.SQLite.Linq version=1.0.103
```

As a trial, I created a simple wpf application with nothing in it but a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I added one table to the model. When I try to generate the database from the model, System.Data.SQLite Database File is available and chosen as the Data Source. But when I try to generate the SQL script I get the error:

[image: Error Message when generate DDL attempted]

The DDL Generation Template is set to SSDLToSQL10.tt. Are there templates for SQLite?
Here is my Config file

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Any ideas?